# Why is it bad to change between uncontrolled and controlled input in React?

Tags: reactjs

I know how to avoid/fix that and how/when to use controlled or uncontrolled input, but changing between uncontrolled and controlled input clearly works, so why is it not officially supported?

And not only that, but some React component libraries, such as Atlaskit provide inputs that exhibit this behavior.

Not even the official docs mention *Why it matters* [react.dev~changing-an-uncontrolled-input-to-be-controlled](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#im-getting-an-error-a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-to-be-controlled)

> If you provide a `value` to the component, it must remain a string throughout its lifetime.
>
> You cannot pass `value={undefined}` first and later pass `value="some string"` because React won’t know whether you want the component to be uncontrolled or controlled. A controlled component should always receive a string `value`, not `null` or `undefined`.
>
> If your `value` is coming from an API or a state variable, it might be initialized to `null` or `undefined`. In that case, either set it to an empty string (`''`) initially, or pass `value={someValue ?? ''}` to ensure value is a string.
>
> Similarly, if you pass `checked` to a checkbox, ensure it’s always a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that switching from a controlled component to an uncontrolled component will not throw an warning, but on the contrary it will. I guess it is because the user may forget to handle the onchange event from uncontrolled to controlled, resulting in a bug，so React throw a warn to help developer avoid these issue.